# How does PGL$_2(K)$ act on $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am currently reading "Algebraic Geometry" by J. Harris, specifically I am trying to learn about algebraic groups, but I am having a few problems. Here is a passage (p. 117) that I struggle with:

[image]

1. Could I think of the action of GL$_2(K)$ on $V$ as just the normal matrix vector multiplication by choosing a basis for $V$?
2. What exactly is Sym$^2(V)$? I have read online that it is a subspace of $V \otimes V$, containing all the symmetric tensors, for example is $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ such a tensor, where $e_1, e_2$ are a basis for $V$. A natural action of GL$_2(K)$ on Sym$^2(V)$ could be $A(x \otimes y) = Ax \otimes Ay$. Is that correct so far? Also, could I for simplicity just think of Sym$^2(V)$ as being the space of symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices?
3. If 1. is true, then one could think of the action of PGL$_2(K)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ as $[A][x]=[Ax]$ right? Since invertible matrices map 1-dimensional subspaces to 1-dimensional subspaces.
4. How exactly does PGL$_2(K)$ now act on $\mathbb{P}($Sym$^2(V)$$)$? How is the action defined? I can see why $\mathbb{P}($Sym$^2(V)$$)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$, since they both have the same dimension.
5. Why do we need char($K$)$\neq 2$? Do we need it because we divide by $2$ at some point?

Edit:
Just to make sure that I understood correctly: since Sym$^2(V)$ has dimension 3, it is isomorphic to $K^3$, so there is some isomorphism $\Phi:K^3 \rightarrow$ Sym$^2(V)$. Now we can define an action of GL$_2(K)$ on $K^3$ by: $A \cdot (a,b,c) = \Phi^{-1}(A(\Phi(a,b,c)))$.

In the same way we can also get an action of PGL$_2(K)$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$. First, we consider the action of PGL$_2(K)$ on $\mathbb{P}($Sym$^2(V)$$)$ by $[A]\cdot [x\otimes y] = [Ax \otimes Ay]$. Then, there is a isomorphism $\Psi : \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}($Sym$^2(V)$$)$, so we define the group action of PGL$_2(K)$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ to be: $[A] \cdot [a:b:c] = \Psi^{-1} ([A](\Psi([a:b:c])))$

Is this true so far?

Comment: To answer 5, there is still an action for $p=2$, it's just that the action looks very different, and was probably excluded for simplicity. In general, the action on $\mathrm{Sym}^n(V)$ behaves in a generic way for $p>n$, and for $p\leq n$ all sorts of other stuff can happen.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes, then no. 3. Yes. 4. Using the action from 2. Any matrix action induces an action on the set of lines. $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ is just a $3$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you look at my edit?

Comment: The most direct way is to think of $Sym^d(V)$ as the vector space of formal homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $V$. If $V$ has basis $x,y \in V$, then a basis for $Sym^2(V)$ is $x^2, xy, y^2$. The action is by having $g \in GL_2$ act directly on the polynomials factor by factor and term by term, e.g. $g \cdot (x^2 + 2xy) = (g\cdot x)(g \cdot x) + 2 (g\cdot x)(g \cdot y)$.

Comment: Your bullet point #2 is totally correct on both counts as well. Though, given the source you’re referring to, I suspect Joe Harris is planning to use the “degree d polynomials” version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What exactly do you mean when you write "$x^2$" for example? Thats not squaring a vector, right? Or is it like this: If $e_1, e_2$ is a basis for $V$, then $e_1 \otimes e_1, \frac{1}{2}\left(e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1 \right), e_2 \otimes e_2$ is a basis for Sym$^2(V)$, and now we now let those tensors correspond to polynomials by doing $e_1 \otimes e_1 \mapsto x^2$ and so on. We then define the action on a polymial by basically turning it back into a sum of tensors, then apply the action as in #2 and then turning it back into a polynomial? Like in the edit?